# Redux saga "rootSaga has been cancelled"

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am new to react redux. 
Just trying out Redux Saga and encountering some error messages that I couldnt comprehend.
This is my rootSaga:

```
import { takeEvery } from 'redux-saga';
import { AUTH_LOAD_SUCCESS,AUTH_SIGNUP,AUTH_SIGNIN,AUTH_SIGNOUT } from '../reducers/auth';
import { receiveAuth,signUp,signIn,onSignOut } from './auth';

export default function* rootSaga(){
    yield [
        takeEvery('AUTH_LOAD_SUCCESS', receiveAuth),
        takeEvery('AUTH_SIGNUP', signUp),
        takeEvery('AUTH_SIGNOUT',onSignOut),
        takeEvery('AUTH_SIGNIN', signIn)          
]
```

}

SignIn and SignUp works perfectly for me but after that I get the following error messages in my console. So even though I can log in using redux-saga but I can't get SignOut to work presumably due to saga being "cancelled" as per the error messages. Can someone please explain to me what's going on? Thanks

```
bundle.js:79457 uncaught at check call: argument fn is undefinedlog @ bundle.js:79457
bundle.js:79457 rootSaga has been cancelled 
bundle.js:79457 uncaught at rootSaga 
 at rootSaga 
 at signIn 
 Error: call: argument fn is undefined
    at check (http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/bundle.js:79313:12)
    at getFnCallDesc (http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/bundle.js:80311:21)
    at call (http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/bundle.js:80336:24)
    at signIn$ (http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/bundle.js:81213:47)
    at tryCatch (http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/bundle.js:7893:41)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/bundle.js:8167:23)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/bundle.js:7926:22)
    at next (http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/bundle.js:79727:28)
    at currCb (http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/bundle.js:79801:8)
    at http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/bundle.js:79904:17
```

Extra info:

```
sagas/auth.js
import 'babel-polyfill';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import { put,call,select } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { requestSignUp,requestSignIn,requestSignOut,receiveUser,receiveSignIn,receiveSignOut } from '../reducers/auth'



export function* onSignOut(){

/////////////////ignore this for the moment///////
 console.log("ffss")

}

export function* receiveAuth() {
    const user = cookie.load('username');

    yield put(receiveAuth(user));
    }

export function* signUp(action) {
    yield put(requestSignUp())
    try {
        const response = yield call(fetch,'/api/sign_up', {
                    method:'POST',
                    headers:{'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                    body: JSON.stringify(action.payload)  /////action.payload contains {username:'aa',password:'aa'}
                    })
        if(response.ok){
            yield call(cookie.save,'username', action.payload.username)
            yield put(receiveUser(action.payload.username))
            yield call(browserHistory.push('/chat'))
        }
    } catch (err){
        throw err
      }       
}

export function* signIn(action) { console.log("hi")
    yield put(requestSignIn())
    try {

        const response = yield call(fetch,'/api/sign_in', {
                method:'POST',
                headers:{'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify(action.payload)  /////action.payload contains {username:'aa',password:'aa'}
                })


        if(response.ok){
             yield call(cookie.save,'username',action.payload.username)
            yield put(receiveSignIn(action.payload))
            yield call(browserHistory.push('/chat'))
        }
    } catch (err){
        throw err
      }
}
```

I think I am expected to put in a second argument to call but when I coded null ie `yield call(browserHistory.push('/chat'),null)` I still get the errors

```
uncaught at signIn call: argument fn is undefined
uncaught at check call: argument fn is undefined
```

Also, my receiveAuth is returning this msg:

```
uncaught at rootSaga 
 at rootSaga 
 at receiveAuth 
 Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the signIn saga? it looks like that is where the exception is being thrown

Answer (score 17):

The error comes from a `yield call(somefunc, ...)` you have inside the `signIn` saga. It says that `someFunc` ( whatever name it has in your code) is undefined. So you should check if you havent mispelled the function name or maybe omitted to export it from its defining module

**EDIT**

I noticed that you call the browserHistory.push function like this

```
yield call(browserHistory.push('/chat'),null)
```

You should not call the function yourself but provide the function itself along with the arguments (and eventually the this context) to the saga

```
yield apply(browserHistory, browserHistory.push, ['/chat'])
```

I'm using the [apply Effect](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#applycontext-fn-args) which allows calling methods with a `this` context (context is provided as a 1st argument)

Comment: There are two calls that could be causing the problem. Please see extra info I added. Could you please tell me how they should be corrected?

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! BTW I see you are a fan of Naruto

Comment: @YassineElouafi I wanted to know that has apply method been removed? Because I can't find it in the documentation

Comment: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#applycontext-fn-args